# Excel columns, how to organize two columns based on a 3rd column which has their email address?

Tags: excel, matching

I am new to Excel. I've been searching for hours for an answer to this, but I've yet to find a tutorial to follow. I think what I want is fairly simple. I have 1 worksheet that looks like this:

```
employee_workday_id    email
f349822220Z32          laura@gathering.net
f99990zewFgvX          kwan@gathering.net
f44320009SS21          sam@gathering.net
```

And I have a 2nd worksheet that looks like this:

```
employee_netsuite_id    email
558422                  laura@gathering.net
558213                  kwan@gathering.net
552199                  sam@gathering.net
```

I don't need the email in the final worksheet, but I'd like to use the email to match the two employee ids. In other words, I need to get this:

```
employee_workday_id    employee_netsuite_id
f349822220Z32          558422                  
f99990zewFgvX          558213                  
f44320009SS21          552199
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Check out index() with match(), so match the email then index based on the position of the matching result.

Comment: Or `XLOOKUP()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, many q&a on here doing this, but here is another:

[image]

To save you typing, here is one example:

```
INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(A16,$B$2:$B$4,0))
```

As the other is so similar, I won't repeat it.

Comment: Thank you for this. But would this work where the columns are uneven? I believe the data from Netsuite has employees who have left the company (1337 rows). The data from Workday is only active employees (907) rows.

Comment: Yes, if match() does not find an exact match then it errors. You can test this by changing something in your data - worth it just for the experience.